# When is the earliest an async_write completion handler will complete?

Tags: c++, boost

Consider a `Connection` class in a `boost::asio` TCP server program that looks something like this.

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_HPP
#define CONNECTION_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace Transmission
{
    class Connection
    {
    public:
        using SocketType = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket;
        explicit Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : m_socket{io_service},
            m_outputBuffer{},
            m_writeBuffer{},
            m_outputStream{&m_outputBuffer},
            m_writeStream{&m_writeBuffer},
            m_outputStreamPointer{&m_outputStream},
            m_writeStreamPointer{&m_writeStream},
            m_outputBufferPointer{&m_outputBuffer},
            m_writeBufferPointer{&m_writeBuffer},
            m_awaitingWrite{false},
            m_pendingWrites{false}
        {

        }

        template<typename T>
        void write(const T& output)
        {
            *m_outputStreamPointer << output;
            writeToSocket();
        }

        template<typename T>
        std::ostream& operator<<(const T& output)
        {
            write(output);
            m_pendingWrites = true;
            return *m_outputStreamPointer;
        }

        std::ostream& getOutputStream()
        {
            writeToSocket();
            m_pendingWrites = true;
            return *m_outputStreamPointer;
        }

        void start()
        {
            write("Connection started");
        }

        SocketType& socket() { return m_socket; }

    private:
        void writeToSocket();

        SocketType m_socket;

        boost::asio::streambuf m_outputBuffer;
        boost::asio::streambuf m_writeBuffer;

        std::ostream m_outputStream;
        std::ostream m_writeStream;

        std::ostream* m_outputStreamPointer;
        std::ostream* m_writeStreamPointer;

        boost::asio::streambuf* m_outputBufferPointer;
        boost::asio::streambuf* m_writeBufferPointer;

        bool m_awaitingWrite;
        bool m_pendingWrites;
    };
}

#endif
```

Where `writeToSocket` is defined as follows:

```
#include "Connection.hpp"

using namespace Transmission;

void Connection::writeToSocket()
{
    // If a write is currently happening...
    if(m_awaitingWrite)
    {
        // Alert the async_write's completion handler
        // that writeToSocket was called while async_write was busy
        // and that there is more to be written to the socket.
        m_pendingWrites = true;
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, notify subsequent calls to this function that we're writing
    m_awaitingWrite = true;

    // Swap the buffers and stream pointers, so that subsequent writeToSockets
    // go into the clear/old/unused buffer
    std::swap(m_outputBufferPointer, m_writeBufferPointer);
    std::swap(m_outputStreamPointer, m_writeStreamPointer);


    // Kick off your async write, sending the front buffer.
    async_write(m_socket, *m_writeBufferPointer, [this](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t){

        // The write has completed
        m_awaitingWrite = false;

        // If there was an error, report it.
        if(error)
        {
            std::cout << "Async write returned an error." << std::endl;
        }
        else if(m_pendingWrites) // If there are more pending writes
        {
            // Write them
            writeToSocket();
            m_pendingWrites = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Incase it's not immediately obvious, the connection uses a double-buffering system to ensure that no buffer is both being `async_writen` and mutated at the same time.

The piece of code I have a question regarding is:

```
   std::ostream& getOutputStream()
   {
       writeToSocket(); // Kicks off an async_write, returns immediately.
       m_pendingWrites = true; // Tell async_write complete handler there's more to write
       return *m_outputStreamPointer; // Return the output stream for the user to insert to.
   }
```

such that a connection can be used like: `myConnection.getOutputStream() << "Hello";`

Specifically, this code relies on an assumption that `async_write`s completion handler *will not be executed until after we return `*m_outputStreamPointer`*. **But can we safely make that assumption?**

If, for instance, the async_write completion handler completes like the following, nothing would be sent to the user:

```
   std::ostream& getOutputStream()
   {
       writeToSocket(); // Kicks off an async_write, returns immediately.
       // Async_write's completion handler executes.
       m_pendingWrites = true; // Tell async_write complete handler there's more to write
       // Completion handler already executed so m_pendingWrites = true does nothing.
       return *m_outputStreamPointer; // Return the output stream for the user to insert to.
   }
```

After looking at the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html), I found this:

`Regardless of whether the asynchronous operation completes immediately or not, the handler will not be invoked from within this function. Invocation of the handler will be performed in a manner equivalent to using boost::asio::io_service::post().`

Which likely accounts for the correct behavior, but I'm not sure exactly why. Did a quick search on `boost::asio::io_service::post()` but that didn't add much clarity.

Thank you,
~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation bit you quote merely says that the handler will not be invoked before return *on the current thread*, so in a single-threaded world you have your guarantee.

However if you have multiple threads running io tasks (`io_context::run` and friends, or implicitly using `thread_pool`), there is still the same race.

You can counter-act this posting all async tasks related to a connection on a `strand` ([Strands: Use Threads Without Explicit Locking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html), which is an executor that serializes all tasks posted on it (see [ordering guarantees](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context__strand.order_of_handler_invocation) in the docs).